# Skip or replace undefined value from result set (API call) in angular

Tags: angular

I'm querying an API which gives back a list of results. The model is the following.

```
result
     {id1
     name1
     fieldList1{}
     }

     {id2
     name2
     fieldList2{}
     }

     {id3
     name3
     fieldList3{}
     }
```

fieldList1, fieldList2 and fieldList3 are an array of the following fields.

```
fieldList1
     id
     field1
     field2
```

The problem I'm facing is that field2 is not always defined because it's not in the returned results, but I want it in my own model. So field2 is required and I want (if the field is not there) replace it with an 0. So I can show an replacement message in the html if it's 0.

I tried with the following code to loop over the results, put it in a new array and replace if undefined:

```
this.resultList.push({id: i.id, field1:  i.field1, field2: i.field2 ? 0 : i.field2});
```

This still gives me the undefined error message and when I switch the if statement all my field2's are put on 0 even if it was there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to interchange your query like this -

```
this.resultList.push({id: i.id, field1:  i.field1, field2: i.field2 ? i.field2 : 0});
```

That mean if `i.field2` present then set as it is its value else 0.

Comment: I tried doing that, but all fields2 got 0 even if they were filled in before. E.g. with value 5

Comment: No, this should not, For Example with value it should be something like this - `this.resultList.push({......, field2: 5 ? 5 : 0});` so it will always return `this.resultList.push({......, field2: 5});`

Comment: Ok, I tried it again and that was indeed the issue. Guess that there was another issue that I fixed in the meantime.

Comment: Might be the case issue with somewhere else, Anyways your welcome @Rafie :)